# It is possible to clear a cookies only on a specified HTTP route on ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies, routes

It is possible to clear a cookies only on a specified HTTP route on ExpressJS?
the case is i only want to clear some cookies on a very spesific route, because when i do this:

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie('foo');
    res.render('login', {
        layout: 'layout/main-layout.ejs',
        page_title:'Login',
     );
});
```

its clear those cookies for all the following route directory, for example the cookies on `/dashboard` route will also be cleared.

Comment: [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie) may help

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cookies for a specific route by doing below example.

```js
res.clearCookie('foo', { path: '/' })
```

Above code clear the cookies in the root directory. If you want to remove cookies in another directory (let's take admin) you can change the directory from "/" to "/admin" and the code will clear the cookies in the /admin directory.

You can read about this more at [Express Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.clearCookie)

If you found this answer helpful mark this answer as the correct answer.